# The scalar multiple of one vector with two other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Prove or disprove:

$(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=\vec{A}\cdot\vec{C}) \rightarrow \vec{B}=\vec{C}$

When all vectors are not $\vec{0}$ and are in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the inner product $\langle \,\,, \, \rangle$ be the standard dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. for $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \cdot B = \langle A,B\rangle$). Now, recall that the dot product is non-degenerate. This means that for a fixed $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, if $\langle A, B \rangle = 0$ for all $B$, then $A=0$. (Here $0$ denotes the vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with every component $0$). So, to prove your statement, we rewrite the left-hand side of the implication using inner product notation: 
\begin{equation}
\langle A, B\rangle = \langle A, C \rangle \Rightarrow \langle A, B-C \rangle=0
\end{equation}
Now, if $\langle A, B-C \rangle = 0$, then all this says is that $B-C$ is orthogonal to $A$, and you can choose a non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that this is true. However, if we consider that $\langle A, B-C \rangle = 0$ for all $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $B-C$ must be zero by the non-degenerate property of $\langle \, , \rangle$.

Added in response to OP's comment:
If you don't consider inner products, you can imagine the equation as $$A \cdot B = A \cdot C \Rightarrow A \cdot (B-C)=0$$Assume $B \ne C$. If the above equation holds for all $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then let $A=B-C$. Then we have $(B-C)\cdot (B-C)=0$ or $||B-C||^2=0$. This implies that $||B-C||=0$ which shows that $B-C$ must be the zero vector (this is the only vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with norm (length) of $0$). However, since this implies that $B=C$ this is a contradiction, since we assumed $B \ne C$. Therefore, our assumption that $B \ne C$ was wrong, and $B=C$.

Comment: Note HR's condition that A be an *arbitrary* vector.  If it is true that for **all** vectors, A, $A\cdot B= A\cdot C$, then it is true that B= C.  If that is only true for **some** vectors it certainly is not true.  For example, in $R^3$, A= <1, 0, 0> has 0 dot product with both B= <0, 1, 0> and C= <0, 0, 1> but B is **not** equal to C.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's a good example. Also, Joshua Gray, I appreciate the effort, but I didn't get to inner products yet. Can you answer that same question without using them?

Comment: @eontorch see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an **arbitrary** vector then you can consider it to be different basis vectors $\left\{ {{b_1},{b_2},...,{b_n}} \right\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$,  then your assumption implies that

$$\left( {B - C} \right) \cdot {b_i} = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,i = 1,2,...,n$$

and hence $B-C$ is a zero vector as its dot products with basis vectors are zero and hence $B=C$.

Comment: Your terminology is at best ambiguous and at worst wrong. You mean something like "if the statement holds for *every* vector $A$, then the result is true".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I really didn't mean such a thing. My answer says

$$ if \,\, [(A \,\,is\,\, arbitrary\,\, and\,\, A \cdot (B-C) = 0] \,\, then \,\, B-C=0$$

Comment: I don't think "arbitrary" means what you think it means

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Can you tell me what is wrong with this answer? What does "arbitrary" mean? I mean by that $A$ is not a fixed vector for example $(1,1,1)$, it can be any vector!

Comment: @user247327: would you please up-vote me! somebody unfairly down-voted my true answer! :(

Comment: @eontorch: would you please up-vote me! somebody unfairly down-voted my true answer! :(